# automate script to transfer files using sftp

Tags: unix, sftp, file-transfer

i need to write a script to automate file transfer from one server to another using only sftp .Can you guys provide me some example sftp automated script ??? or some code that would help me !!!

Comment: Can you code in Perl or Python or similar?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979812/automate-sftp-upload-process) for some suggestions. Additional details for your server environment would be helpful (LINUX, Windows, etc.).

Comment: the file which has to be trasfered exists in mainframes server and i need to gete it on an usix server

Comment: You'll need to see what sftp programs are available in your server environment.